# Prevent retrofit query parameters from being escaped

Tags: android, gson, retrofit, retrofit2

The endpoint I need to query accepts a key called `exams` which is an array so the idle url to query it would be

```
https://example.com/api/v1/search?exams[]=6&exams[]=7&page=0
```

So far this is my retrofit interface function that calls it

```java
    @GET("search")
    Observable<CustomResponse> search(@Query("search") String query,
                                      @Query("class") int class_id,
                                      @Query("exams[]") ArrayList<Integer> examIds,
                                      @Query("page") int page);
```

The final call that gets executed turns into

```
https://example.com/api/v1/search?exams%5B%5D=6&exams%5B%5D=7&page=0
```

How do I prevent this from happening and send an array as a query param. THis is a GET request not a POST.

Comment: it's not escaped, it's encoded. Did you test it? It should work as is

Comment: @TimCastelijns yeah my bad, I meant encoded, I did and for some reason I am getting an encoded url, I expected it to work as well because every site online says that it should work as is.

Comment: @Ranjan The request I'm making is a GET not a POST

Answer (score 1):

Try this -

```
@GET("search")
Observable<CustomResponse> search(@Query("search") String query,
                                  @Query("class") int class_id,
                                  @Query(value = "exams[]", encoded = true) ArrayList<Integer> examIds,
                                  @Query("page") int page);
```

Comment: It should work. From the documentation >Parameter names and values are URL encoded by default. Specify {@link #encoded() encoded=true}
 * to change this behavior.
Maybe you have to put `encoded` `true` for all queries.

Comment: I have a working example of this but also have single query parameter in it.